# Create different type of classes via Symfony/Console

Tags: php, symfony, console, laravel-artisan

I've setup the Symfony Console on a custom php app (not a Symfony app, just using the component outside of Symfony), and created an `app` file under my root directory

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
// Include framework's dependencies through composer's autoload feature
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$application = new Symfony\Component\Console\Application();

// ... register commands
$application->add(new TestCommand());

$application->run();
```

This is a test class I've set up

```
<?php

namespace Mvc\Commands;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

class TestCommand extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name of the command (the part after "bin/console")
     * 
     * @var string
     */
    protected $command_name = 'app:test';

    /**
     * The description of the command (the part after "bin/console")
     * 
     * @var string
     */
    protected $command_description = "Try to echo Hello World for testing if it works.";

    protected function configure()
    {
        $this->setName($this->command_name)
             ->setDescription($this->command_description);
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $name = $input->getArgument($this->command_argument_name);
    }
}
```

How can I create commands to generate different type of classes, like how for example Laravel does for generating controllers, models etc (`php artisan make:controller TestController` etc)?

Comment: The artisan code as well as the Symfony maker bundle code is all open source and available on github.  Typically you will have a controller template class in which you inject controller specific values.

Comment: This is what I''m trying to do, set some class templates and pull them in the *Commads classes, but haven't found anything on Symfony's documentation on how to do this https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console.html

Comment: This is not part of the Symfony docs. Instead you have to either research how Laravel does this, e.g. by studying one of their [commands, like ModelMakeCommands](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/ModelMakeCommand.php), or [Symfony's MakerBundle](https://github.com/symfony/maker-bundle). You might even want to build on their foundation. As of now, I am afraid, this question is too vague to be answered meaningfully. If you get stuck during your research, feel free to open a more specific question for the problem you have.

Comment: @dbrumann if you want you can write it as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 0):

You must install maker-bundle with `composer require symfony/maker-bundle --dev`

after this, write `php bin/console make` and press enter for showing all the available commands.

Comment: Is this specific to Symfony or I can use it outside of the Symfony too? the project I'm on is a custom one, not based in any of the known frameworks